# How to swap 4 int8 integer to a int32 variable in C

Tags: c, swap

I have a 8 bytes integer buffer carrying data bytes, and a 32 bytes variable to save these data. How can I swap data bytes to variable except use pointer? (use pointer will case some unknown issue).

Ex.

```
buffer[0] = 0;
buffer[1] = 1;
buffer[2] = 2;
buffer[3] = 3;
```

How to shift `buffer[0]` to variable bit `[31:24]` , `buffer[1]` to variable bit `[23:16]`, `buffer[2]` to variable bit `[15:8]`, `buffer[3]` to variable bit `[7:0]`.

Comment: I wonder if bit manipulation could help. Read about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
uint32_t variable;
buffer[0] = 0;
buffer[1] = 1;
buffer[2] = 2;
buffer[3] = 3;
variable = ((buffer[0] << 24)| (buffer[1] << 16) | (buffer[2] << 8) | buffer[3]);
```

When I used a 32bit varible the data type declearation i used was uint32_t ,please make sure that you use it otherwise use your declarations for uint8_t & uint32_t

Comment: note, this only works if `buffer` is `unsigned char`.  If it might have negative values then you have to modify the calculation to make sure those values are converted to `unsigned char` first.